# No funcionan los Data Annotations en un formulario

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, razor

Tengo un formulario para persistir datos con `entity framework`, le pongo `DataAnnotations` a mi modelo, pero aún así no me validan los valores, no me aparecen los mensajes de **error**, si no pongo nada en el campo nombre o en el `select` de género, al guardar, me arroja una excepción:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.`. Que está pasando?

**Modelo**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Lista.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = " El {0} debe tener entre 2 y 10 caracteres")]
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Debe elegir sexo")]      
        public Gender StudentGender { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Gender
    {
        Male,
        Female
    }
}
```

**Controlador**:

```
using Lista.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Lista.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private pruebaEntities db = new pruebaEntities();

        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var sudent = new Student();

            var items = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Male", Value = "Male"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Female", Value = "Female"},
    };

            ViewData["Genders"] = items;

            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Student st)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Student.Add(st);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View(st);
        }
    }
}
```

**Vista**:

```
@model Student
@using (Html.BeginForm("CrearCliente"))
{
<br />
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StudentName)
    @Html.DropDownList("StudentGender", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Genders"], "Select Gender", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StudentGender)
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" />
}
```

Comment: en la vista tienes agregado   @section Scripts {@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") } ?????

Comment: Revisaste el detalle de la excepción? Que te indica? A simple vista todo parece estar bien

Comment: dice "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar a construir tu mismo el html de la siguiente manera.
Yo en lo personal me gusta construir yo el html, creo que de alguna manera le facilito el trabajo al servidor de que tenga que renderizar todos los controles para después mostrarlos

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="StudentName" value="@Model.StudentName">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s.StudentName)
</div>

<select name="StudentGender">
    <option value=""></option>
        @foreach (var gender in ViewData["Genders"])
        {
            <option value="@gender.Id">@gender.Name</option>
        }
</select>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProfesionId)
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda este ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Se parece que te falta el JQuery validation.

Asegura que tienes el siguiente en la vista:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Imagino que vas a tener que cambiar el path.

O incluirlo en el bundle (si lo estas usando)

Comment: no me funcionó, me hace lo mismo. Pude comprobar que los scripts están cargados.

Comment: no son cosas diferentes la validación de jquery y la validación del lado del servidor?

Comment: Puedes revisar en los Developer Tools (F12) Y mirar el source a ver si los tags estan ahi. Los Data Annotations son en el servidor, pero estan pasado al cliente. Si miras el source vees algo como data-val="true" data-val-required="The Blah field is required."

Comment: los tags están. porque no funciona?

Comment: <input id="StudentName" class="text-box single-line" name="StudentName" value="" type="text">

Comment: <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="StudentName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

Comment: eso es lo que me aparece con f12

Comment: Intenta dos cosas. Asegura que <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" /> es en appSettings en el web.config. y en el GET pasa el modelo: return View(sudent); (pero debe ser student).

Comment: intenté eso y me sigue dando el mismo error